# Makefile .for and .if expansion

Tags: makefile, freebsd

I'm wanting to run a Makefile with

```
.if "${WITH_DOT}" != "0"
VIS+=       day21.dot day21.pdf
.endif
```

but I'm getting

```
Makefile:17: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

The only link I could find was https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2005-February/010281.html

Why isn't this working? How do I run this?

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is part of *(Free)BSD* Make's syntax. The *GNU* Make's syntax differs, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Example):

```
libs_for_gcc = -lgnu
normal_libs =

foo: $(objects)
ifeq ($(CC),gcc)
        $(CC) -o foo $(objects) $(libs_for_gcc)
else
        $(CC) -o foo $(objects) $(normal_libs)
endif
```

You can check FreeBSD's make manual page [here](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make#INCLUDE%09STATEMENTS,_CONDITIONALS_AND_FOR_LOOPS) (scroll down a little for `.if`). If you want use this make I think you should install `bmake` or `bsdmake` package.

The loops, conditionals aren't part of [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) so these features can be differ (if exists) in different make-variations.